# Fingerprint connected to Web Server via Get/Post method

Tags: api, post, tcp, fingerprint

I'm going on develop web api server (php) that has an attendance feature
client need me to make fingerprint-direct-to-webserver I created

So, my question is what is the easy way to accomplish this requirement?

- Does it have any Fingerprint that already be able to do this? (connected to PHP web server, or it has an API to reply what data inside it?) [If it already in market, I might not need to created it]
- Does anyone ever do this before, I'm looking on some IP Fingerprint (such as BIOEntry / BioStation series), I'm little worried that, is it has some encrypted key also or not, if it has it might be problem for me. could you give the fingerprint product name?
- How fingerprint send the data? (GET/POST? TEXT/XML/JSON? If you have some copy/paste of its data, it would help me alot)

Comment: As Arifin said, you will need some kind of middleware. You could build your own, but I think that will take a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there some middleware solutions available to integrate fingerprint attendance with web based applications. [Bio-Plugin™](http://www.m2sys.com/bioplugin/) is one of them that can be integrated with your  web api server (php). Also encrypted key might be available now. The system send fingerprint data thorugh SOAP protocol. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Almost the same web api exist in the market. API details are http://camsunit.com/application/biometric-web-api.html.